# How can I get <Redirect ... /> to refresh the page after redirect in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I am updating form data using api. So I created a form component that renders the data into the form. I have created a "device_detail" component. In this component I have added a "update" button which links to update_device_detail component. In my update_device_detail component I have a method handleUpdate:

```
handleUpdate(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  const ied = this.props.match.params.id
  if (this.validateMainForm()) {
    let elements  = this.state.element
    let items     = this.state.type_items
    const data    = {
      id: items['id'],
      name: items['name']
    }
    console.log('--------final-data before posting-------', data);
    axios({
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/foo/'+ied+'/update',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      data: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      return response
    })
    alert('Device Updated Succesfully!!!')
    this.setState({redirect: true})
  }
}
```

I have set initial state of `redirect: false` .

In render() method I have made a condition statement:

```
if (this.state.redirect) {
    return <Redirect to={`/device/${this.state.items.id}`} />
  }
else {
      return(
       ...)
  }
```

Redirect is taking me to right page, but the updated data is not reflected on detail page. But when I press refresh button manually It gets reflected. Is there a way I can make  to force refresh the page on which it is redirecting or is there any other way to achieve the same.

Comment: What if you put your `this.setState({redirect: true})` in the `.then` of your promise, because what i can see is that you redirect before receiving the HTTP response. I'm not sure this is the cause of your problem but that's already one issue

Comment: No need for reload. Where is the data that is shown on device_detail page saved, redux or state of some component? Wherever it is you need to update that too with the data received from api in `then` part of your axios. Also your `setState({ redirect: true })` should be inside then of `axios`. Otherwise it will redirect even beofre data has been saved on server

Comment: @VaibhavVishal The redirect was happening before the data has been saved on server. It worked  Thank you

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond putting this.setState({redirect: true}) inside .then solved the problem